# How does the construct "n'en soulève pas moins" work?

Tags: grammaire, sens

Read this sentence:

> Pour légitime et nécessaire qu'elle soit, une telle question n'en soulève pas moins d'emblée une
>   difficulté, semble-t-il, insurmontable.

I do not understand what the "en" refers to and what "moins" does here. I understand "d'emblée" to mean "right away" or "just like that" here, but "moins" just seems redundant to me.

Could someone help me understand the meaning of this construct?

Comment: Asking about the construct is fine, but note that asking for a translation into English is off-topic here.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Rephrased.

Comment: Ok, great. If someone thinks of an equivalent construct in English, they can mention it. It shouldn't be necessary to answer the question though. The focus should be on explaining the construct. That's why we prefer to keep posts free of translation requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"***Moins***" is not redundant, removing it would reverse the meaning of the sentence:

- "*ne soulève pas*" means "doesn't raise"

while

- "*ne soulève pas moins*" means "nevertheless raise".

"***En***" refer to "*légitime et nécessaire*", i.e. "*ne soulève pas moins du fait qu'elle soit légitime et nécessaire...*"

The sentence might be simplified this way:

> *Bien que légitime et nécessaire, cette question soulève immédiatement une difficulté qui semble insurmontable.*

Insoluble questions are often little appreciated but the context should better explain why the author put in opposition "legitimate and necessary" and "insurmountable". Here is a guess about what (s)he had in mind:

> *Bien que la question s'impose (et mériterait d'avoir une réponse satisfaisante), elle semble cependant insoluble (et voici pourquoi on ne sait pas y répondre...)*.

Note that "***pour ... que***" is used in a rare, literary way to introduce a concessive clause (similar to *even though* or *despite* in English), like this excerpt from the [TLFi *pour* entry](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pour) shows:

> C.− [Marque l'idée de concession]
>   ...
>   2. *Pour* + adj. + *que* (+ subj.). *Il (...) lui jura que, pour grand que fût son amour, son amitié l'emportait de beaucoup encore* (Gide, *Caves*, 1914, p. 763). *Ce succès, pour modeste et incomplet qu'il fût, m'apparaissait comme une première étape vers la victoire* (Joffre, *Mém*., t. 2, 1931, p. 61). *Je me sentais perdu et, pour absurde que cela paraisse, j'eus un bref mouvement de désespoir* (Bosco, *Mas Théot.*, 1945, p. 108).

Comment: Je ne pense pas que le contexte se prête à une concessive; il se traite sur le plan d'une coordination,  simple ( « et ») ou moins simple (« mais »)  et préférable dans ce cas parce que l'auteur veut exprimer que  sa résolution entraine des difficulté ; « Cette question est légitime et nécessaire mais elle soulève une difficulté qui semble insurmontable. »

Comment: @user168676 Ce n'est pas du tout ma compréhension de la phrase. L'utilisation de *pour* correspond pour moi bien ici à une concession.

Comment: Oui, je comprends que « pour » établisse une concession, seulement je considère qu'il n'existe pas un contexte sur la base de la concession et que l'auteur n'utilise pas des termes reflétant la  relation qui existe vraiment de par les éléments qu'il met en cause. Je dois ajouter cependant que le contexte de concession est bien défini dans les exemples que vous ajoutez à partir du TLFi.

Comment: @user168676 Comme souvent, on ne connaît rien du contexte réel et cette phrase est inconnue des moteurs de recherche. Avant de juger l'auteur, attendons que Cadaniluk nous en dise plus...

Comment: On n'a pas besoin d'autre chose il me semble : la nécessité et l' importance ne peuvent pas entrer dans  une concession à la difficulté ; en simplifiant on a ceci : « Bien que ce soit important c'est difficile. » ; Cela n'est pas  du bon raisonnement.

Comment: @user168676 *Bien que la question s'impose, elle est cependant insoluble* ne me semble pas illogique.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83027/discussion-between-user168676-and-jlliagre).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the context should not be the best for this use of « en … pas moins », that is the author used this form when he/she might have done better to use something else, as I see it; to expand a little on what I am saying I'd say that it is not at all obvious that because a question is legitimate and necessary it should also not raise a problem and be difficult. Although this is not a form I can find in the dictionary it is fairly familiar to me, but I find it in contexts that seem more appropriate; here is an example of use I think irreproachable.

- Tout puissant qu'il soit, il n'en est pas moins sans ressources contre de simples moustiques.

« en » refers to the power ; what is then said is a remark on what one would think could result from that power but which, surprisingly enough, doesn't: nevertheless, irrespectively of all that strength, he is vulnerable if attacked by simple mosquitoes.

The two words are used together as far as I can remenber. However, there is a way do use something else instead of "moins"; the construct is changed slightly.

- Tout puissant qu'il soit, il n'en est pas plus protégé contre de simples moustiques.

This inversion shows that "moins" is not a redundant word in the sentence.